# How to check if a column value is in a string SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I have a database with 150,000 records and I need to match its FULL column value or records, with some parts of the string. 
**

> As i want to check if the **STRING** contains the **COLUMN** records and NOT!
>   if the COLUMN contains the string

**
*(Example below)*

For testing purposes 
Lets say the database has a ***TABLE*** , 1 ***COLUMN*** and 1 record as the records are similar to this:

> - **come to me**

and i need to match it with this ***@STRING***

> - She wants to **come to me** now

I want to execute something similar to :*(but this doesn't work of course)*

```
SELECT * from TABLE where @STRING like '%'+COLUMN+'%'
```

I can't seem to solve this with SQL the usage of PHP is possible but prefer if the solution is with SQL but if the solution with PHP is available please propose it *and note that the database has over 150,000 records*

Comment: I don't see the point of doing such query. Can you please explain what do you need it for? Basically I think you are trying to implement FULLTEXT search which is well documented in docs.

Comment: This would be used as a kind of basic censoring system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * from TABLE where LOCATE(COLUMN, @STRING)>0;
```

LOCATE(a,b) returns a number giving the character location of a in b, or returns 0.

See [Mysql LOCATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate)

The docs discuss that LOCATE() is only case sensitive when one of the strings is a 'binary string'. That probably doesn't affect your use case, though if it became an issue you could CONVERT() the binary strings to a locale and use LOWER() to get lower case.

[MySQL String Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html)

Comment: @Undefined Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

The dynamic like syntax for mysql is

```
SELECT * from TABLE where @STRING like CONCAT('%',COLUMN,'%')
```

Comment: Perfect solution but i chose the LOCATE, Thank you for your help i will be using this solution for other issues